# "debug on device" in sony ericsson phones

Tags: android

Can someone please explane how to enable debug on device in my Sony Ericsson x-10 mini device?
I don't know how to install the appropiate drivers for this phone in my PC.

Comment: you need to provide more details. which OS your are using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official guide, should be enough, have fun! http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: It doesn't explane about the specific sony erricsson driver.

Comment: it's just a usb driver to recognize the phone on windows, there's not a driver for any given brand. you'll be notified that you can enable debug on the phone as soon as you connect the usb wire (along with mass storage but you can't enable both together)

Comment: +1 this guide/link got me up and running with a Sony Ericsson Experia whatever in seconds

Answer (score 1):

You should find driver for your device. In your case you should download driver from [this](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/dw-x10minidrivers?cc=gb&lc=en) page. After that you have to install this driver. Simply unpack the zip archive, find .inf file and install it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using win os you need to download the driver from this [link](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/driver?cc=gb&lc=en)

if your are using linux your need to add Sony Ericsson  vendor ID `0FCE` in the rules file.